# Timestamp and substring with regular expression

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, regular-expression, substring

I am using postgresql and I have the following table

```
          Table "public.test"
 Column |           Type           | Modifiers 
--------+--------------------------+-----------
 name   | text                     | 
 time   | timestamp with time zone | 


 name  |          time          
-------+------------------------
 ticka | 2016-07-08 21:22:58+00
(1 row)
```

When I do the command:

```
select substring(name from '.*') from test;
```

I get a result, but when I do it for the time column I get:

> Error: LINE 1: select  substring(time from '.*' ) from test; 
>                   ^ 
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Why is this? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, because the function is called substring, I think it only works for the string data type but not for the timestamp data type

To solve this I use the regular expression on the timestamp by converting the timestamp into a text first using the `to_char` function and then I use the substring function as follows:

```
select substring(to_char(time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') from '.*') from test;
```

Comment: Please tick the tickmark on your answer, that is the indicator of solved issues, not the [solved] tag in the title.

Comment: haha, sorry for this, i thought that i have to added manually